# php foreach each result in one variable

Tags: mysql, variables, foreach, php

I am trying to get each result of a query into one variable so that I can include it into my wp_mail message.

This is what I am using.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * 
                               FROM $tableName 
                               WHERE userId = $user_ID 
                               AND status LIKE '1'"
                            );
foreach( $result as $key => $value)
{
    $string .= $value.',';
}

echo $string;
$email = $_POST['parentsEmail'];    
$child = $_POST['childsName'];
wp_mail( $email, "".$child." has finished", "".$child." has completed the following ".$string." ");
```

I have been searching and found another thread asking something similiar and this was suggested.

```
$string .= $value.',';
```

However when I try to do the same thing, I get

Catchable fatal error: Object of class `stdClass` could not be converted to string in

Comment: Value is an array right? Don't you need to explode the array or implode it?

Comment: what are you getting in `$result`? do print_r or var_dump

Comment: make sure you get one row

Comment: Yea I always end up with array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concat rows field in SQL statement with [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(field_name) AS concat_alias
    FROM $tableName
    WHERE userId = $user_ID AND status LIKE '1'
";
echo $string = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
```

Comment: if you are using gropu_cancat, then you have to use group by.

Comment: @kumar_v: not in this case.

Comment: I end up with array? How do I get the contents of the array?

Comment: @user1949929: I have just updated the answer, where you fetch using [`get_var()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Variable).

Comment: @user1949929: np, glad I can help. If you wish to use different separator, you can set that in [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function like: `GROUP_CONCAT(field_name SEPARATOR ' | ')`...

Comment: Thanks I used (optionName SEPARATOR '\r\n') works great.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this instead using mysql

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(col1,col2,col3) `value`
FROM $tableName 
WHERE userId = $user_ID AND status LIKE '1'
```

You can use this instead using mysql ok